# Imageview - Definindo o Drawable por caminho por Path

Tags: android, android-layout, imagem

Olá estou iniciando no Android e estou com um pequeno projeto que seria um jogo da memória.
Então para "embaralhar os cards" criei uma função que armazena em um array de inteiros chamado ***codimg*** números de 1 a 12 aleatórios e diferentes. Dentro da pasta *drawable* tenho 12 imagens que possuem o mesmo nome alterando apenas o final com uma numeração.
Tenho também um array de ImageView chamado ***imagens***

Para setar as imagens tenho usado as linhas abaixo

```
for (i = 0; i <= codimg.length; i++) {

           File file = new File("/app/src/main/res/drawable/img" + codimg[i]+".png");

           imagens[i].setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
       }
```

Entretanto algo tenho feito de errado pois retorna o erro abaixo para todas as imagens, elas não são encontradas.

*.jogodamemoria E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/src/main/res/drawable/img11.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)*

O caminho e exatamente como aparece.

Espero que possam me ajudar, grato!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha sugestão para esse caso é usar a **API de Resources** para isso. Dado o nome do *resource* é possível recuperar seu identificador com o método abaixo:

```
public int getImageDrawableResId(String imageId) {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    return resources.getIdentifier(imageId, "drawable", getPackageName());
}
```

Pra usar basta chamar passando o nome do `drawable`:

```
for (i = 0; i <= codimg.length; i++) {
    int drawableId = getImageDrawableResId("img" + codimg[i]);
    Drawable dr = getResouces().getDrawable(drawableId);

    imagens[i].setImageDrawable(dr);
}
```